# Magento. Register variable doesn't work

Tags: magento, global-variables

I try to register global variable in magento, but it's doesn't work.
In /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php I register variable:

```
Mage::register('g_addressType', $addressType);

$mylog = print_r(Mage::registry('g_addressType'), true);
Mage::log("address_type1:".$mylog, null, 'mygento.log');

$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/');
```

In /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php I try to get this variable:

```
$mylog = print_r(Mage::registry('g_addressType'), true);
Mage::log("address_type2:".$mylog, null, 'mygento.log');
return Mage::registry('g_addressType');
```

But it doesn`t work. I get this log:

```
2013-06-04T13:38:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): address_type1:private
2013-06-04T13:38:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): address_type2:
```

Where is the mistake? I use magento 1.7. Yes, I know that I can not make changes in core files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because the Magento registry is not persistent on page load. And changing from CartController (/checkout/cart/) to OnepageController (/checkout/onepage/) means reloading the page so your g_addressType is not kept between the two.

A better thing to do would be to use session like this :

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setGAddressType($addressType)` in CartController.php

then

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getGAddressType()` in OnepageController.php

Last reminder though: please make sure not to code this in Core Magento files. Please extend existing core classes.